# How to solve font intercepting issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am working on the website but I am going through some error and I really don't know exactly how to solve it. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Here is the issue:

[image: This is how it looks on desktop]

But in mobile is is working fine:

[image: Mobile view]

Website link: [Check the product section here](http://www.ambrosianuts.com/products.html)

Please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @Sagar Shelke It might be the issue of `position`.

Comment: It's your use of `display: -webkit-box` on the list items. Use `display: flex` instead and see if it works out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `display:flex;` instead of `display: -webkit-box;` for below css class:

```
.product-lightbox-contentbox li{
    display:flex;
}
```

**line no: 627 in product-page.css file**

Comment: Thanks @JonathanStellwag :)